# tvOS 14 can't reduce Searchbar font size

Tags: uisearchbar, tvos

I was trying to reduce the tvOS searchBar font size but no luck.

```
 if #available(tvOS 14.0, *) {
        UILabel.appearance(whenContainedInInstancesOf: [UISearchBar.self]).font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 38.0)
        UITextField.appearance(whenContainedInInstancesOf: [UISearchBar.self]).font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 38.0)
    }
```

[image]

Any recommendation or solution to this?

Comment: Can you customise the UILabel that is added in the screen.

Comment: @Senthil That is a searchbar text